# Raster categorical attributes not showing in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r

I created a `landcover classification` raster using a `dataframe` in `R`. The raster `attributes` show as intended in `R`, but after saving the raster and loading it in `ArcGIS` the `character` attributes don't show up, as the open attribute table option is greyed out.

What step am I missing before saving the raster? Maybe I have to use the `raster::ratify` function, but I  am not sure at what step was I suppose to use it.

Sample Data

```
X    Y    class
1    1    C
2    1    D
3    1    A
4    1    C
5    1    D
1    2    D
2    2    C 
3    2    D
4    2    B
5    2    D
1    3    D
2    3    C
3    3    A
4    3    C
5    3    B
1    4    B
2    4    D
3    4    C
4    4    C
5    4    D
```

Code

```
    library(raster)
    
    # Create a factor column out of the class column
    df$fclass = factor(f$class)
    
    # Create a numeric class column from the factor column
    df$nclass = as.numeric(df$fclass)
    str(df)
    
    # Now make a new raster from this
    df_rstr = rasterFromXYZ(df[, c("x", "y", "nclass")])
    
    # Convert the raster to a factor with the levels from the factor in the data frame
    df_rstr[] = factor(levels(df$fclass)[df_rstr[]])
    
    # Set CRS
    projection(df_rstr) = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
    
    # Write to disk
    writeRaster(df_rstr, "~/dummy.tif", overwrite = T)
    
    df_rstr
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4, 5, 20  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0.5, 5.5, 0.5, 4.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : nclass 
values     : 1, 4  (min, max)
attributes :
 ID VALUE
  1     A
  2     B
  3     C
  4     D
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tif raster with categorical values will always store the information as Integer, then a look up table is used by different softwares to translate the information from the numerical value to its labels. In orde to optimize the size, Byte should be used if less than 255 categories.

In ArcGIS, the raster will be considered as a categorical raster if it is associated with a "raster attribute table". This table, which stores categorical information and optionnally the text labels, is a specific dbf table. It can be done in ArcGIS with the command "build raster attribute table". Then you can either manually edit the table to add your text label (writing each category one by one), or add the information using a joint table (if you have a large number of classes, this will be faster).

I haven't tested, but [R can create dbf files](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/write.dbf.html). So you could automatically make the attribute table in R. The file must have the same name as the raster (with a *.tif.vat.dbf extension). OID, VALUE and COUNT are required columns (integer type), then you can add additionnal columns (e.g. LABEL with the text code). OID are identifiers of the rows (starting at 0, increasing by 1), VALUE are the different integer values stored in the raster, COUNT is the number of pixels for each value.

Comment: So, I have managed to create the dbf as mentioned in your answer, but `ArcGIS` is still not picking up the `dbf` upon loading the raster. even though of both the `raster` and `dbf` have the same name. Even the columns are the [same](https://app.box.com/s/4sh29xxsokftz3cf1nzckdm0wpknl08l) as suggested. Do I need to need to run some additional steps in `ArcGIS`?

Comment: Make table view for raster and join field. You can delete dbf after.

Comment: @FelixIP, do I need to convert the raster to `Int` before doing this, because right now the `Make Table View` returns `ERROR 000229: Cannot open ~\dummy.tif
Failed to execute (MakeTableView).`?

Comment: Yes, if it's not integer. Otherwise Build Raster table first. Do it from mxd.

Comment: So, I have another update, apparently, `ArcMap` is not evening recognizing the created [dbf](https://app.box.com/s/8r76suwjm97hehuduz5tpbnadmrst7hv) file as a `dbf` file, even though the file opens just fine in `R` using the `read.dbf` function and in `MS-Excel`. What could be the issue here?

Comment: As I've said I didn't test dbf from R. Column type must be integer (it seems to be decimal number on your print screen). ArcGIS uses dbase 4, but I don't think that it is the problem. If you have less than 255 classes, better store your raster in Byte

Comment: also, not sure that it is important, but the order of the columns should be OID - VALUE - COUNT (your example is OID -COUNT- VALUE )

Comment: I think that you should first try to work in ArcGIS before testing the automated dbf in R. As I wrote in my answer, use "Build raster attribute table" to create your dbf file (which you can then compare with your output from R)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works, just posting this to show how I got it working in `R` after creating the raster table in `ArcMap` (thanks to radouxju). Load the raster `dbf` in `R` and attach the `categorical column` and save it back and load the raster again in `ArcMap`.

```
    # Import the dbf

    library(foreign)
    dummy_dbf = read.dbf("~/Dummy_Int.tif.vat.dbf")
    
    # Create the Class column
    Class = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
    
    # Append
    dummy_dbf$Class = Class
    
    # Save to disk
    write.dbf(dummy_dbf, file = "~/Dummy_Int.tif.vat.dbf)`
```

[image]